# Как отсортировать массив с датами Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, playground

Мне необходимо отсортировать некий массив с датами. Даты хранятся в массиве в виде строк.

```
func dateForm() -> String{
let formatterDate = DateFormatter()
formatterDate.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let someThing = Date()

let result = formatterDate.string(from: someThing)


return result
}

var date = dateForm()


var array = ["29/01/2019", "03/10/2019", "31/01/2019", "29/01/2016", "01/01/2020"]


array.sort()
```

.sort() выдаёт это:

```
["01/01/2020", "03/10/2019", "29/01/2016", "29/01/2019", "31/01/2019"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как вариант через обратное приведение в дату

```
var array = ["29/01/2019", "03/10/2019", "31/01/2019", "29/01/2016", "01/01/2020"]

func compareDates(_ first: String, _ second: String) -> Bool {
    let formatterDate = DateFormatter()
    formatterDate.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return formatterDate.date(from: first)! < formatterDate.date(from: second)!
}

array.sort { compareDates($0, $1) } // ["29/01/2016", "29/01/2019", "31/01/2019", "03/10/2019", "01/01/2020"]
```

или

```
var array = ["29/01/2019", "03/10/2019", "31/01/2019", "29/01/2016", "01/01/2020"]

array.sort {
    let formatterDate = DateFormatter()
    formatterDate.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return formatterDate.date(from: $0)! < formatterDate.date(from: $1)!
} // ["29/01/2016", "29/01/2019", "31/01/2019", "03/10/2019", "01/01/2020"]
```

Comment: Стоит помнить, что создание экземпляра DateFormatter - очень дорогая операция. Для лучшей производительности стоит создать его один раз, и при сортировке применять каждый раз один и тот же экземпляр

Comment: @DmitrySerov полностью согласен, делал на скорую руку)